# Use array from parameters.yml in routing.yml

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-2.4

I got a locales declaration in my `parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    locale:            en
    locales:           [ en, de, fr, it, es, pt, ru, ja, zh ]
```

and want to reuse the `locales` param in `routing.yml`

```
homepage_locale:
    pattern: /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteBundle:World:index }
    requirements: { _locale: %locales% }
```

But this obviously results in

```
The container parameter "locales", used in the route configuration value 
"%locales%", must be a string or numeric, but it is of type array.
```

Is there a way to reuse this param or do I really have to write the locales as a string to satisfy this yaml/regex format, like this:

```
en|de|fr|it|es|pt|ru|ja|zh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about it:

```
parameters:
    locale:            en
    locales:           en|de|fr|it|es|pt|ru|ja|zh
```

Comment: :) nice try, but I'm already using the `locales` parameter in lots of other places and simply want to avoid duplicate declaration.

Comment: use `find text in files` and replace all :)

Answer (score 4):

In src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

you can add in load function this code

```
    $languages = $container->getParameter('languages');
    $container->setParameter('languages_string', implode('|', $languages));
```

Then you will can use in your annotation

```
     *     requirements={"_locale": "%languages_string%"},
```

It prevent from duplicate parameters in your config file.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea if you have just one bundle. If you split your project into multiple bundles, then it seems not appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you must try

```
_locale: en|de|fr|it|es|pt|ru|ja|zh
```

Good look

Comment: Sure that would work, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.